# Specify line separator in BigQuery schema file

Tags: python, google-bigquery

The following is the schema file I have:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "first",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
   ]
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "gs://xy-bq/nonstandard.csv"
  ]
}
```

How would I specify the line-separator of `"\x01"` here?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the example schema file [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource-representations). What you want is:

```
"csvOptions": {
  "fieldDelimiter": "\u00ff"
},
```